# Finding libssl on a customer's Linux

Tags: linux, openssl, libraries, shared-library

We're using a library which needs to load `libssl` in a version `1.0.*`. It doesn't work with `libssl.so.1.1`. We need it to work on any Linux system.

We try to load various versions and this usually works, but on system of one customer there's just the following:

```
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1.0g
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2m
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1
```

We're trying to load `libssl.so.1.0` and `libssl.so.1.0.2`, but it doesn't find `libssl.so.1.0.2m` because of the trailing "`m`".

I wonder what's the naming scheme of libssl, if any?

Do we really need to provide our own version or is there a better way?

Should we loop from `libssl.so.1.0.2z` down to `libssl.so.1.0.2a`? Should we scan the library path manually?

Comment: `ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2m /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2` *might* work.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro There are two problems with it: 1. Knowing the exact name. 2. It's a customer's computer.

Comment: The bigger problem might be not having a test system then. Test the `ln`, is harmless and can be removed easily. See also @mjturner answer, it recalls important details.

Comment: How are you distributing your library? Don't try to *find* a compatible copy of OpenSSL on someone else's computer that you have no control over - bring the copy with you. The most reliable way is to distribute a known-compatible copy of the necessary OpenSSL libraries with your own library.  Put the OpenSSL shared object(s) in the same directory as your library then find and `dlopen()` it, or statically link OpenSSL and build your shared object(s) so they incorporate the OpenSSL object files from the OpenSSL static libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're opening `libssl` - I assume `dlopen()`?

Searching a hard-coded list of directory paths for a library sounds rather fragile - you'd be better off letting the dynamic linker do the work for you. Perhaps parsing the output of `ldconfig -p` is worth trying? On a Debian system, I see the following:

```
$ ldconfig -p|grep ssl
libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
libssl.so.1.0.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
```

On a RHEL 7.4 system:

```
$ ldconfig -p|grep ssl
libssl3.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libssl3.so
libssl.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libssl.so.10
```

Note that on the Debian system the library is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, whereas on the RHEL system it's in `/lib64` (also note the widely varying library names). Unless you use something like the output of `ldconfig`, you're going to have to search all of those distribution-specific paths yourself if you plan to "work on any Linux system". Admittedly, the directory paths are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` but I think using `ldconfig` is probably still easier.

Comment: I think the OP is not in Debian. +1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was told, the problematic system is Fedora; anyway we need a solution for any Linux desktop . But `ldconfig` and/or `/etc/ld.so.conf` may be portable enough.

Comment: I agree, that is why I voted you up.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Indeed, but the same solution should apply. `ldconfig -p` should work on any Linux system (I've just confirmed and added some detail).

Comment: You understand I just commented it was not Debian, right?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I did :)